# calculate statistics for the dataframe based on a column information

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

There is a dataframe looks like as follows, which only shows 4 records

```
Identification      cost              weekdays
1001                $20.02            Tuesday
1002                $30.03             Monday
1004                $20.05            Wednesday
1006                $10.05            Tuesday
```

In Pandas, how to calculate the statistics, such as mean, standard deviation of the cost on each weekdays. Should I use groupby, and how to use it for this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may contain two part , first convert accounting type data to numeric , then `groupby` with `agg`

```
df.cost=df.cost.replace( '[\$,]','', regex=True ).astype('float')
df.groupby('weekdays').cost.agg(['mean','std'])
Out[958]: 
             mean       std
weekdays                   
Monday     30.030       NaN
Tuesday    15.035  7.049855
Wednesday  20.050       NaN
```